# Is there a way to have one DB set to Antelope and another DB set to Barracuda on the same shared hosting server?

Tags: mysql, innodb, barracuda

Now my MySQL (5.6) uses Antelope as the file format. for another system I need the DB to be set to Barracuda file format.

Is there a way to have one DB set to Antelope and another DB set to Barracuda on the same shared hosting server?

The same question regarding innodb_large_prefix - can I set it only to one DB in a shared hosting server without changing it to all the DB on this shared hosting server?

Thanks!
Ram

Comment: Seems like a question for your hosting provider.

Comment: Hi,
I guess that the problem is that in order to set the file format to Barracuda my service provider will have to changed it for all the shared hosting server - unless there is a way to do it only on one DB - and this is what I trying to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* have two instances of MySQL talking to the *same* set of files.  Not even if everything is identical.

You *can* have two instances of MySQL, each with its own, separate, copy of the data.

You can have two instances of MySQL, one "replicating" from the other, with the *same* data, but separate disk files for this copies of the data.

When a single instance of MySQL is running with Barracuda, it can (in theory) have some tables that are using Antelope.  The `VARIABLE` in `my.cnf` controls the "max".  That is, when set to B, it can handle A or B.  When set to A, it cannot handle B.  (Note: they eventually eliminated both.)

Which do you really want?

`innodb_large_prefix` is related.  (Note, also, that it has been removed in a later release.)  Perhaps this is really what you need -- 5 ways to deal with a certain error:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

Comment: Thanks!
Eventually I was able to change it all to barracuda.